# Remove Fly-out Menu from Quick Launch Bar

Tags: 2013, jquery, quick-launch

After hours of research I am not able to find a way to remove the fly-out menu from the quick launch bar without changing the master page.  I tried by changing the Tree View settings, as well as quick launch bar settings.  None were successful.  Is there a way to apply JQuery script into a script editor web part.  For an example, please see below.  Thanks for any help.

**Fly-out Menu**

[image]

**Non Fly-out Menu**

[image]

**Update**
Further research... if I add the following to a script editor  What do you think?

```
    <style type="text/css">  
  .ms-core-listMenu-item
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you tweak what you have there - and adding the display characteristic of "none" to it - that should get done what you are looking for. I can't speak for it's behavior in 2013 as I haven't tried it there - but I have used that technique with tons of success in 2007 and 2010 to remove items in a specific site collection without havin to impact the master page for the whole company intranet.

```
<style type="text/css">  
  .ms-core-listMenu-item
{
 display: none;
}
</style>
```